# focusout event of a div element in angular 8 is triggered each time any of it's focusable child elements loses focus

Tags: javascript, angular

When a container is bound to the focusout event which contains focusable elements, it's focusout event is triggered each time any of it's focusable child elements loses focus!

What do I do for controlling this? I need to do something if the user clicked out of a div.

Comment: in your method, add event parameter, and first line you can write event,stopPropagation();

i beleive it will work in your case.

Comment: @Rajsingh I checked it but did not work :(

Comment: in angular, you have to pass parameter to the calling method, $event.  Can you please share the code snippet if possible ?

Comment: @Rajsingh I checked that event.relatedTarget is child of the element (that has the focusout event) or not and the problem solved, I did it with passing $event and #element to the method.

Comment: if the solution work for you then you may upvote it :)